# OpenCV Unhandled Exception at 0x1050FBFE (opencv_world300.dll)

Tags: c++, opencv

**** ~~>  Updated <~~  **

Hi, I get the following error from my code below:

*(My aim is to Find a special image on list of images called Template Matching. 
I add opencv_world300 to debug and release in visual studio 2012 but I don't know what's causing this error)*

> Unhandled exception at 0x01DDABBA (opencv_world300.dll) in OpenCV.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000FB97

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEZIT.png)

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

void fastMatchTemplate(cv::Mat& srca,   cv::Mat& srcb,   cv::Mat& dst,   int  maxlevel)   
{
std::vector<cv::Mat> refs, tpls, results;

cv::buildPyramid(srca, refs, maxlevel);
cv::buildPyramid(srcb, tpls, maxlevel);

cv::Mat ref, tpl, res;

for (int level = maxlevel; level >= 0; level--)
{
    ref = refs[level];
    tpl = tpls[level];
    res = cv::Mat::zeros(ref.size() + cv::Size(1,1) - tpl.size(), CV_32FC1);

    if (level == maxlevel)
    {

        cv::matchTemplate(ref, tpl, res, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
    }
    else
    {

        cv::Mat mask;
        cv::pyrUp(results.back(), mask);

        cv::Mat mask8u;
        mask.convertTo(mask8u, CV_8U);


        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
        cv::findContours(mask8u, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::Rect r = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
            cv::matchTemplate(
                ref(r + (tpl.size() - cv::Size(1,1))), 
                tpl, 
                res(r), 
                CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED
            );
        }
    }

    // Only keep good matches
    cv::threshold(res, res, 0.94, 1., CV_THRESH_TOZERO);
    results.push_back(res);
}

res.copyTo(dst);
}

int main()
{
cv::Mat ref = cv::imread("G:\\reference.png");
cv::Mat tpl = cv::imread("G:\\template.png");
if (ref.empty() || tpl.empty())
    return -1;

cv::Mat ref_gray, tpl_gray;
cv::cvtColor(ref, ref_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::cvtColor(tpl, tpl_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

cv::Mat dst;
fastMatchTemplate(ref_gray, tpl_gray, dst, 2);

while (true)
{
    double minval, maxval;
    cv::Point minloc, maxloc;
    cv::minMaxLoc(dst, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc);

    if (maxval >= 0.9)
    {
        cv::rectangle(
            ref, maxloc, 
            cv::Point(maxloc.x + tpl.cols, maxloc.y + tpl.rows), 
            CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2
        );
        cv::floodFill(
            dst, maxloc, 
            cv::Scalar(0), 0, 
            cv::Scalar(.1), 
            cv::Scalar(1.)
        );
    }
    else
        break;
}

cv::imshow("result", ref);
cv::waitKey();
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you added the dll folder to the PATH? Or have you copied the dll in the same directory of the exe?

Comment: Please include the error text, not a screenshot.

Comment: People do not like pictures of errors (or code).